# In Google App Engines, how to display the HTML source of a page of a fetched URL in Python?

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, url, fetch

On Google App Engine I found this code that is fetching a web page's URL:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
url = "http://www.google.com/"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
  doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
```

Is this the right code to fecth that page's HTML source? Does the *result* variable contain HTML sorce of http://www.google.com/? If yes, what Python command I should use here instead of  *doSomethingWithResult(result.content)* in order to display that HTML source? *print result* doesn't seem to be the right way.

Comment: Did it worked for you ?The code not working for me !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `result.content` will contain the raw content of that page.  You should check the `Content-Type` header and verify that it's either `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`.

To write the content of that page to the response, first write your status and headers and then:

```
self.response.out.write(result.content)
```