# Sending the variable's content to my mailbox in Python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, header, content-type

I have asked this question here about a Python command that fetches a URL of a web page and stores it in a variable. The first thing that I wanted to know then was whether or not the variable in this code contains the HTML code of a web-page:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch
url = "http://www.google.com/"
result = urlfetch.fetch(url)
if result.status_code == 200:
doSomethingWithResult(result.content)
```

[The answer that I received was "yes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868587/in-google-app-engines-how-to-display-the-html-source-of-a-page-of-a-fetched-url), i.e. the variable "*result*" in the code did contain the HTML code of a web page, and the programmer who was answering said that I needed to "*check the Content-Type header and verify that it's either text/html or application/xhtml+xml*". I've looked through several Python tutorials, but couldn't find anything about headers. So my question is where is this Content-Type header located and how can I check it? Could I send the content of that variable directly to my mailbox?

[Here is](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html) where I got this code. It's on Google App Engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the Google App Engine documentation for the [response object](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/responseobjects.html), the result of `urlfetch.fetch()` contains the member `headers` which contains the HTTP response headers, as a mapping of names to values. So, all you probably need to do is:

```
if result['Content-Type'] in ('text/html', 'application/xhtml+xml'):
    # assuming you want to do something with the content
    doSomethingWithXHTML(result.content)
else:
    # use content for something else
    doTheOtherThing(result.content)
```

As far as emailing the variable's contents, I suggest the Python [email](http://docs.python.org/library/email) module.

Answer (score 1):

for info on sending Content-Type header, see here:
 http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview.html#Request_Headers